# Refresh google maps after kmz change

Tags: google-maps, google-api, maps, refresh, page-refresh

I run a website [noticestomariners.com](http://www.noticestomariners.com) I convert data into xls and then into kmz files and use Google api code (via viewpoint, I believe) to draw different map baseds on the kmz files stored on my server. The KMZ files draw points of current notices to mariners.

Every day I add new points and take off the expired points and generate a new kmz file.

I need the google maps to refresh itself based on the new kmz file. At the moment, google maps will only refresh if I change the filename. But I have hundreds of maps. I assume the kmz file is cached somewhere.

Is there anyway the google map can be refreshed without changing the name of the kmz file?

I hope this makes sense. Any help appreciated.

Bob Brandis

Answer (score 0):

Suppose some function create new `.kmz` file..say `CreateNewKMZ()`

Just run the google map's initialize function in the end line of the function `CreateNewKMZ()`

```
CreateNewKMZ(){
    //Do something to create new .kmz file
    //initializeMap();
    initMap();
}


function initMap(){ 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 6, center: {lat: -37.814, lng: 144.96332} }); 
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ url: 'noticestomariners.com/KMZ/Bribie.kmz';, map: map }); 
}
```

Comment: So, do I add that after the function initMap()

Comment: Here is what I have so far.function initMap()
 {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 6,
center: {lat: -37.814, lng: 144.96332}
});
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'http://www.noticestomariners.com/KMZ/Bribie.kmz',
map: map
});
}
</script>
<script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBjk74a5OhSp3k7Cs1J3aIbgZdVuByc8W4&amp;callback=initMap">
</script>

Comment: @BobBrandis yes.. i update the answer.. this way you don't have to rename files and with every update to file..map get refreshed and reinitialize...

Comment: I am obviously doing something wrong. <script>
CreateNewKMZ(){
//Do something to create new .kmz file
//initializeMap();
initMap();
}
{
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 6,
center: {lat: -37.814, lng: 144.96332}
});
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'http://www.noticestomariners.com/KMZ/Bribie.kmz',
map: map
});
}
</script>
<script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBjk74a5OhSp3k7Cs1J3aIbgZdVuByc8W4&amp;callback=initMap">
</script>

Comment: Where is your changing kmz file script?? Check update.. I'll have to see where you are writing the function to update the .kmz file

Comment: I am so sorry. Please forgive my ignorance. But I do not know what the "changing kmz file script" means or looks like. Is it the script async=" " ... I also do not know how to copy the code in those forum in the format you have above otherwise I would copy the whole code if it would help.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170656/kmz-file join the room to chat

Comment: I am updating the file on the server. The kmz file loads correctly on google earth pro which updates immediately. However it does not update the google maps file. Google maps is the most appropriate style for the webpage.

Comment: well it cant be done until/unless server tell the webpage about the changes... either you can constantly check from webpage by sending http requests from webpage or you can use `server push api` to tell browser about the change..

Comment: I found this line does the trick 'http://www.xxxxxxxxx.kmz?timestamp='+new Date().getTime(),
map: map
});

Comment: great :D can u give me some reference to update the answer so other get the help too?